# Find text enclosed by patterns using sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed, sh

I have a config file like this:

```
[whatever]
Do I need this? no!

[directive]
This lines I want
Very much text here
So interesting

[otherdirective]
I dont care about this one anymore
```

Now I want to match the lines in between `[directive]` and `[otherdirective]` without matching `[directive]` or `[otherdirective]`.

Also if `[otherdirective]` is not found all lines till the end of file should be returned. The `[...]` might contain any number or letter.

### Attempt

I tried this using `sed` like this:

```
sed -r '/\[directive\]/,/\[[[:alnum:]+\]/!d
```

The only problem with this attempt is that the first line is `[directive]`and the last line is `[otherdirective]`.

I know how to pipe this again to truncate the first and last line but is there a `sed` solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the range, as you were trying, and inside it use `//` negated. When it's empty it reuses last regular expression matched, so it will skip both edge lines:

```
sed -n '/\[directive\]/,/\[otherdirective\]/ { //! p }' infile
```

It yields:

```
This lines I want
Very much text here
So interesting
```

Comment: hmm, the only problem is that I don't really know otherdirective, this is while I used `/\[[[:alnum:]]+\]/` but the `-n` flag and these `{ ... }` commands are exactly what I was searching for! And if I try that it wont return the correct solution

Comment: Okay wtf I tried it again and you're right it works even if I substitute `\[otherdirective\]/` just forgot to add `-r` again! 
thx much smaller and `//!` is a handy trick!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nice way with `awk` to get section of data.

```
awk -v RS= '/\[directive\]/' file
[directive]
This lines I want
Very much text here
So interesting
```

When setting RS to nothing `RS=` it divides the file up in records based on blank line.
So when searching for `[directive]` it will print that record. 
Normally a record is one line, but due to the RS (record selector) is change, it gives the block.

Comment: Could you explain why this works. I have really no clue!
Even thought it does not remove the `[directive]` in the beginnig.

Answer (score 0):

Okay damn after more tries I found the solution or merely one solution:

```
sed -rn '/\[buildout\]/,/\[[[:alnum:]]+\]/{
    /\[[[:alnum:]]+\]/d
    p }'
```

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want?

```
\[directive\](.*?)\[
```

[Look here](http://regex101.com/r/oD7yO0)

Comment: Basically yes. Althought the bracket might occure without opening a new directive.
Still how am I supposed to use this pattern in a `bash` command!